# how to remove the "x qty" from product options in email confirmation?

Tags: orders, custom-options, order-email

I want to hide the 'x' + qty in the table of the options of an item in the email order. It shown only when the qty is bigger than 1. I am using advanced custom options.

Comment: what version of magento you are using ?

Comment: magento 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 1):

All email phtml files are located in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/`

You should be able to overwrite that template by copying and pasting it into your theme and remove the qty section.